# Assigning a full matrix using conditionals in Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I want to make an iteration where I change a matrix's elements using pointwise multiplication, but use conditionals to only change some elements.  However, using conditionals with matrices only seems to let you assign a scalar to some elements, not a full matrix.

I tried using conditionals to determine which elements are iterated, but using conditionals changes the dimensions of the matrix to a one dimensional array.

```
y=-1:0.005:1;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=X+1i*Y;
Zn=0*Z;
Iter=0*Z;

for m=1:1000
  Zn = Zn.^2+Z;
  Iter(Iter==0 & (abs(Zn)>10))=m;
endfor

p=pcolor(X,Y,Iter);
set(p,'edgecolor','none')
axis equal
```

Here's my full program.  It iterates over a matrix to do the Mandelbrot graph.  It works fine, but the online lessons I'm doing ( https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s997-introduction-to-matlab-programming-fall-2011/fractals-and-chaos/truth-statements-and-logical-indexing/ ) want you to stop the iterations for elements already larger than 10, to make it more efficient.

Inside the for loop you see the Iter matrix, this does exactly what I want it to.  Since I'm assigning a scalar to certain elements using conditionals works just fine.  Above it though is my matrix that I'm iterating, Zn.  I'd like to write something like Zn(Zn<10) = Zn.^2+Z; but this gives me the error:

```
error: mandel: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 154633x1, op2 is 401x401)
error: called from
    mandel at line 9 column 13
```

Conditionals turn a matrix into a one dimensional array, so this doesn't work.  So my questions are

1. Why would they turn it into a one dimensional array?  This is horribly unhelpful when manipulating matrices.
2. How can I get around this and only iterate certain elements, to make my code more efficient?

Edit: I'm suing Octave 5.1.0 on Windows.

Comment: This is octave specific. `Zn(Zn<10) = Zn(Zn<10).^2+Z(Zn<10)` might work better. Alternatively, as a workaround, convert everything into a vector before the for loop, then reshape it back to a matrix after the loop.

Comment: Thanks David, I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Your idea worked fine.  As for this being Octave specific, the url in my post is for Matlab and that suggests that it's common to that as well.

Comment: I ran it in Matlab and it worked fine, `Iter` was square.

Comment: Iter was always fine.  Assigning a scalar to these matrices with conditionals always works.  You just need your trick for assigning other matrices to them, otherwise you get the error about the dimensions being different.  Why do these conditionals change the dimensions of a matrix in the first place?

Comment: Oh I see now. It's to do with indexing via linear index or subscript I think, and then assigning into an existing matrix affects the behaviour. If the array didn't get flattened, what should be output if you do `A=rand(5);A(A>0.5)`, for example?

Comment: ```ans =

   0.66416
   0.95027
   0.90659
   0.60731
   0.58489
   0.72452
   0.79387
   0.54537
   0.59086
   0.83099
   0.82451
   0.95994
```

Comment: That's a vertical list by the way.  I think this is how matlab does it as well.  In my url above, you see this in middle of the page, above Exercise 18:
```
>> A=magic(4);
>> B=A>10;
>> A(B)
ans =
     16
     11
     14
     15
     13
     12
```